# Kernel Error in Jupyter notebook - failed to start

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I am facing a Kernel Error in Jupyter Notebook.

I am on Windows 10, created a new environment for tensorflow in Anaconda using Python 3.5

Initially, Jupyter Notebook did not start. I was told to downgrade “tornado” to 5.1.1

After downgrading tornado to 5.1.1 (current version), Jupyter Notebook starts but i have the following Kernel error.

Any kind souls can help to advise on the issue. Thank you in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 528, in get
        value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
    KeyError: 'loop'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 457, in wrapper
        result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 62, in post
        kernel_id=kernel_id))
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
        kernel_name)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
        self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel
        super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
        km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 258, in start_kernel
        self.start_restarter()
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\ioloop\manager.py", line 49, in start_restarter
        kernel_manager=self, loop=self.loop,
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
        return self.get(obj, cls)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
        value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 591, in _validate
        value = self.validate(obj, value)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1677, in validate
        self.error(obj, value)
      File "C:\Users\fayas\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1524, in error
        raise TraitError(e)
    traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'loop' trait of an IOLoopKernelManager instance must be a ZMQIOLoop, but a value of class 'tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop' (i.e. <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop object at 0x000002AED01F69E8>) was specified.
[E 15:41:57.102 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "158",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/cellstrat/DL%20Course/CellStrat%20DL%20course%20Mod%201/demo2/Module2_graphs.ipynb",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|1213e26b|cf2abf81e87bb35c13497822b64d0315|1607083322; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1607083520|23:username-localhost-8888|44:OTRlNTYwMGNlZTg0NDlhZTk3Y2NlNDIzNDBiMmIyMzc=|8fb6e08950a5fc84a46daa6b8798530ca0071664e3001824679396a616bbe4fb\""
    }
```

Comment: Activate your `env` and install kernel by calling command `python -m ipykernel install --user`. Thanks!